# How to get the size of a directory in Ada?

Tags: ada

I want to get the size of a directory. Unfortunately, the `Ada.Directories.Size` function raises an exception

> raised ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.NAME_ERROR : file "/some/dir" does not exist

when trying to get a directory size.

**To clarify:** I do not mean the total size of files in this directory, I mean the size the directory itself. When calculating the total size of a directory, compared to a tool like `du` some bytes are missing. These are the directory sizes.

Comment: What is the result of the Ada.Directories.Exists function ?

Comment: For either `Ada.Directories.Size` subprogram, "If the external file is not an ordinary file, the result is implementation-defined."

Comment: @NWS the directory exists, `Ada.Directories.Exists` returns `true`.

@trashgod Does this mean, that with the GNAT implementation, there is no way to get the directory-size with the standard library?

Comment: The idea that a "directory" is stored as a file, whose size and other characteristics can be queried like other files, is highly OS-specific.  So I don't think any such function belongs in Ada.Directories.  The language defines Ada.Directories.Information for OS-specific stuff.  The RM lists the routines that should be available on Unix-like systems, and "directory size" isn't one, but the RM also allows routines to be added to the package, so maybe you can talk your Ada compiler vendor into adding one.  Otherwise you'll have to interface to stat() yourself.

Comment: @Maec: It just means that you'll have to look at the implementations to see why `Size` doesn't match `du`.

Comment: Remember to round up to the same block size both with `du` and in your Ada tool.

Answer (score 1):

the method `Ada.Directories.Size` only works for simple files. To use it on a directory the argument must be of `Directory_Entry_Type` (which can only be constructed with the `Get_Next_Entry` function.

--> use `Start_Search` with an appropriate pattern, such that you only find your desired folder.